# How can I optimize my Zend framework 1.11 Application?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Developed Zend Framework 1.11 Application by using Mysql As a database which consist of 198 tables.This Application contains reports,registration modules.It's Already in Production since one Year.As data grows its becoming slow day by day.

So I think need to optimize this Application ie both zend framework and mysql.

What are all the possible techniques to optimize this Application?

Comment: Figure out what is slow and make those things faster

Comment: I would start with measure what takes time.

Comment: You Mean I need to check the code line by line through out the application?

Comment: Enable slow log in MySQL and set it to about 1-2 sec. Check configuration of your MySQL server if its good for you. Make local copy of your page and enable queries profiling (it send all queries done to your Firebug so you can see how many them are running when you open a page. Install XDebug to make scans of slowest pages.

Comment: you could try using memcached so you don't have to query the db as much: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips to start you off:

- Try to use Caching whereever you can, especially for the Table Meta Data; Zend has some great backends for that: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.cache.html
- As suggested, Log the SQL-Queries with a Profiler. Take the slowest Queries and manually check them with "EXPLAIN":http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html
- Profile the whole application; easily done using the profiler of your favorite IDE, especially Zend Studio or PHPStorm. Reading the profiler output correctly though will require some further reading into that topic

But there is of course a whole lot more to do - but these 3 usually help me with the first 40% performance when i need to make something faster.